# MapControl DataTemplate Binding with an ObservableCollection in WP 8.1 WinRT App

Tags: mvvm, dictionary, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, xaml-binding

How to bind mulitple location in a Maps:MapControl? I have some json data of lattitude & longitude. I have put them in an ObservableCollection in Model class, made a INotifyChangeProperty of it in MainViewModel. Now cant bind the collection in a xaml Maps:MapControl data template. Please help. A simple sample would be much helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you want to to? Do you want to display push pins? A polygon? Multiple MapControls?

Comment: yeah, i want to display custompushpin for the places(As I have some lattitude and longitude of some places) in a map control. @Fred